# Make an autoincrement ID field for EntityFramework table (azure mobile services)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

I have several data classes that maps to database tables using EntityFramework. All these classes are derived from [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Entity.EntityData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.entitydata.aspx) class to auto-fill CreatedAt, UpdatedAt and Version, Deleted fields. The thing is when client application POSTs data to backend the Id field required in post parameters. So the **client** should generate the Id on his side. Therefore no chance to make it autoincrement because client don't know amount of records to generate next id. So the one solution for client is to generate GUID and POST to backend. That is not good for me cause I need to know record number. And also I am not sure if there would be duplicates if i've got billions of records.

Current workaround of this works such way. In TableController class within Post method I am checking if Id field presents and if not then set it up as records count + 1. Here is the code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Id))
            user.Id = (_db.Users.Count() + 1).ToString();

        _db.Users.Add(user);

        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (UserExists(user.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("api_v1", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }
```

The thing I am bothering is what if 2 users will do POST requests and .Count() method returns the same number at that time, so Id's will be the same and conflict appeared. Is it possible case? 
The second thing is I have 12 table controllers and need to put this Id check everywhere. Is there more elegant solution for this?

Comment: why not let SQL/your DB auto gen the ID?! why do it manually?

Comment: I am asking this in question, how to do this? Because by default there is no generation of ID in EntityData class.

Comment: right, I wasn't referring to EF but your actual data storage - SQL. it will auto gen the ID and EF will get that value back. you may need to update the model so it is aware of that condition

Comment: Could you guide me how better to update database to reach autoinc in EF?

Comment: How did you create the tables in the Database? you also need to add the following attribute to your EF class on the ID property: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. Also why is "Id" a string? it shouldn't be. it should be a pure data type such as int or GUID (UniqueIdentifier)

Comment: I can't add any attributes to Id because this field is within EntityData class in separate assembly (...Mobile.Serivce...). I didn't creating table, it creates automatically through EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you shouldn't.

In general, this is bad practice for Mobile Services because it creates problems just like you're describing.

If you need some kind of auto-incremented field, make it generated on the server and remove the dependency on the client.

Comment: Also, Mobile Services requires that IDs be generated on the client. If you want additional fields that are generated on the server, you can do that, but they can't be the ID field.